# Cannot assign requested address on google colab

Tags: websocket, google-colaboratory

I have encountered the following error on a colab notebook:

```
import syft as sy
from syft.workers.node_client import NodeClient
import torch
hook = sy.TorchHook(torch)
nodes = ["ws://localhost:3000/","ws://localhost:3001/"]
compute_nodes = []
for node in nodes:
    compute_nodes.append( NodeClient(hook, node) )
```

The `NodeClient` is actually using functions and classes such as `self.connect()`, `self.ws = websocket.create_connection(**args)`, `websock.settimeout(timeout if timeout is not None else getdefaulttimeout())`, `websock.connect(url, **options)`, `self.sock_opt.timeout = options.get('timeout', self.sock_opt.timeout)`, `self.sock, addrs = connect(url, self.sock_opt, proxy_info(**options),options.pop('socket', None))`, `sock = _open_socket(addrinfo_list, options.sockopt, options.timeout)`, and `sock.connect(address)`.

but it produces the error:
`OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address`.